# Accesing spring context from jaas LoginModule

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jaas

I've implemented a Jaas Login Module, in order to perform authentication. I must access database to retrieve user/pass information within this module.

In the same project, there exists some DAO bean's implemented, but it's impossible to access Spring context from the jaas login module, to retrieve the DAO bean.

¿Anyone could help me please?

I'm using Spring Security to integrate Jaas in my application.

Comment: Have you tried SecurityContextHolder.getContext()? What does this return within your jaas login module?

Comment: SecurityContextHolder is singleton, however it is populated after login module is called. It is specific to Spring Security and contains valuable information after LoginModule is called, not before.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the LoginModule, simply add the interface ApplicationContextAware and a bean definition for the LoginModule. When the application starts the context will be available within the module.
`public class LoginModule implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    } 
}`

Javadoc for the interface:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html

Comment: That does not work, at least with Jetty 9. applicationContext is null

Comment: @JuanCalero - the ApplicationContext must be static as well. This is for the same reason the other beans must be static as well if you want to use them in the LoginModule - instantiation is performed by JAAS, so Spring's dependency injection does not kick in.

Answer (score 0):

JAAS and login modules are loaded and initialized beside primary Spring framework context. This is job done by java platform and it has no knowledge about your intention to use Spring.
For that reason you need to bridge Spring context to your login module via some kind of singleton or holder. Much more elegant way to do that is implementation of your own `AuthenticationProvider` which is legitimate spring bean.

For work around purposes and other people who are interested in getting Spring application context without explicit access to it I would like to provide an example.
Keep in mind that while this way is portable, you might run into various troubles caused by classloader visibility leading to multiple singletons. Be careful when you run this code inside any application server or servlet container.

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

import java.util.Optional;

public class SpringContextHolder implements ApplicationContextAware, InitializingBean {

    private static SpringContextHolder INSTANCE;

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public Optional<ApplicationContext> getApplicationContext() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(applicationContext);
    }

    public static Optional<SpringContextHolder> getInstance() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(INSTANCE);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        INSTANCE = this;
    }
}
```

Your login module can then get access to application context via singleton:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

import javax.security.auth.Subject;
import javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule;
import java.util.Map;

public class TokenLoginModule implements LoginModule {

    @Override
    public void initialize(Subject subject, CallbackHandler callbackHandler, Map<String, ?> sharedState, Map<String, ?> options) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringContextHolder.getInstance()
            .flatMap(SpringContextHolder::getApplicationContext)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Unable to locate Spring context"));

       // lookup via context.getBean or just store it as a field
    }
}
```